# How to list all the find -perm results?

Tags: linux, command-line, find, ls

I want to give a long list (with ls -l) of all the files in home directory that is writable by user, how can I combine find and ls -l?

Answer (score 1):

```
find ~/ -maxdepth 1 -exec ls -l '{}' \;
```

If you are strictly interested only in files, i.e., no folders then you can tune the last command in the following way

```
find ~/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec ls -l '{}' \;
```

Comment: If you find any answer helpful enough, it would be nice from you to accept it. If you still have doubts though, just ask. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Check your man page for "find". It has a -ls action that you can tag on to the end:

```
   -ls    True;  list  current  file  in ls -dils format on standard output.
```

Comment: I already know that but I actually want the ls -l format for the print out